# Authorizenet Get an Accept Payment Page, it is not showing four most recent payment profiles for that customer, how do I do that?

Tags: authorize.net

I am working with PHp, the code is AcceptSuite/get-an-accept-payment-page.php
How do I add to this code so that it shows:
Important: If you use the Customer Profiles feature to store customer payment information, you can send a customer profile ID in the customerProfileId element of the getHostedPaymentPageRequest call. When the browser displays the form, the four most recent payment profiles for that customer profile are displayed as shown in the image below. The customer can choose among these payment methods or enter new payment information, and save the new payment information in a payment profile that can be used in later transactions.

This is from the documentation at https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/accept-hosted.html#AcceptHosted_JSONRequest

```
<?php
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';
  require_once 'includes/classes/SampleCodeConstants.php';
  use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
  use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;

  define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE", "phplog");
    $customerProfileId = "your custome id";


function getAnAcceptPaymentPage($customerProfileId)
{
    $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchantAuthentication->setName(\SampleCodeConstants::MERCHANT_LOGIN_ID);
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(\SampleCodeConstants::MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_KEY);

    $setting = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting->setSettingName("hostedPaymentButtonOptions");
    $setting->setSettingValue("{\"text\": \"Pay\"}");

    $setting1 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting1->setSettingName("hostedPaymentOrderOptions");
    $setting1->setSettingValue("{\"show\": false}");

    $setting5 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $setting5->setSettingName("hostedPaymentBillingAddressOptions");
    $setting5->setSettingValue('{"show": false, "required": false}');

    $customerProfile = new AnetAPI\CustomerProfilePaymentType();
    $customerProfile->setCustomerProfileId($customerProfileId);

    $customerOptions = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $customerOptions->setSettingName("hostedPaymentCustomerOptions");
    $customerOptions->setSettingValue("{\"showEmail\": false, \"requiredEmail\":false, \"addPaymentProfile\": true}");

    $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
    //$transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction");
    $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authOnlyTransaction");
    $transactionRequestType->setAmount(100.00);
    $transactionRequestType->setProfile($customerProfile);

    $hostedPaymentOptions = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $hostedPaymentOptions->setSettingName("hostedPaymentPaymentOptions");
    $hostedPaymentOptions->setSettingValue("{\"cardCodeRequired\": true, \"showCreditCard\": true, \"showBankAccount\": false}");

    $request = new AnetAPI\GetHostedPaymentPageRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
    $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting1);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting5);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($customerOptions);
    $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($hostedPaymentOptions);

    $controller = new AnetController\GetHostedPaymentPageController($request);
    $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);

    if (($response != null) && ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok")) {
        //echo "Hosted payment page token: " . $response->getToken() . "\n";
        return $response->getToken();

    } else {
        echo "ERROR :  Failed to get hosted payment page\n";
    }
}

$token = getAnAcceptPaymentPage($customerProfileId);
?>

<?php
include("include the file with the code");


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<head>
    <title>HostedPayment Test Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            //$("#btnOpenAuthorizeNetIFrame").click(function () {
                $("#add_payment").show();
                $("#send_token").attr({ "action": "https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment", "target": "add_payment" }).submit();
                //$("#send_token").attr({ "action": "https://accept.authorize.net/payment/payment", "target": "add_payment" }).submit();
                $(window).scrollTop($('#add_payment').offset().top - 50);
            //});

        });


</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--     
    <div>
        Open Authorize.net in an iframe to complete transaction
        <button id="btnOpenAuthorizeNetIFrame" onclick="">Show Payment Form</button>
    </div>
-->
    <div    id="iframe_holder" class="center-block" style="width:90%;max-width: 1000px">
        <iframe id="add_payment" class="embed-responsive-item panel" name="add_payment" width="100%"  height="600" border="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" hidden="true">
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <form id="send_token" action="" method="post" target="add_payment" >
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function () {
            if (!window.AuthorizeNetIFrame) window.AuthorizeNetIFrame = {};
                AuthorizeNetIFrame.onReceiveCommunication = function (querystr) {
                    var params = parseQueryString(querystr);
                        switch (params["action"]) {
                            case "successfulSave":
                                break;
                            case "cancel":
                                break;
                            case "resizeWindow":
                                var w = parseInt(params["width"]);
                                var h = parseInt(params["height"]);
                                var ifrm = document.getElementById("add_payment");
                                ifrm.style.width = w.toString() + "px";
                                ifrm.style.height = h.toString() + "px";
                                break;
                            case "transactResponse":
                                var ifrm = document.getElementById("add_payment");
                                ifrm.style.display = 'none';
                            }
                    };

                function parseQueryString(str) {
                    var vars = [];
                    var arr = str.split('&');
                    var pair;
                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        pair = arr[i].split('=');
                        vars.push(pair[0]);
                        vars[pair[0]] = unescape(pair[1]);
                        }
                    return vars;
                    }
        }());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the updated code and it works, hope it helps someone